# What video format for Instagram Sharing Extension to work?

Tags: ios, instagram, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a 13 second video file stored in the Documents directory. When I share it using the UIActivityViewController, the Instagram option does not appear.

All the other sharing extensions appear just fine and work great.
When I "Save Video" to my Photo Library and then navigate to that video on my phone, I can actually share it to Instagram from the Photos app.

I've tried the video in both .mp4 and .mov formats... no luck.

I've verified that the video is only 13 seconds long.

I've verified that the Instagram app is installed and I'm logged in.

Is there a different format I should try?

[image: All options available when I click More]
[image: Sharing menu missing Instagram option]

Comment: Do you implement the delegate method 
`func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController)` to return a placeholder image for your content?  I think that is required in order for Instagram to appear as a sharing option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simply to not pass a "message" parameter.

subject/title parameter is fine but don't set message.

Video format was not the issue.

Comment: Hi, im facing this problem, can you give me an example of the 'video', is it an url at local storage, album or online?

Answer (score 0):

While initialising the UIActivityViewController, in the "activityItems" field don't pass any text parameter, pass only the video file, it worked for me.

eg

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [video], applicationActivities: nil)
```